# Is it possible to generate automatically the reCAPTCHA key pair for a specific domain?

Tags: recaptcha

I generate my DKIM keys with Ansible and AWS route53's DNS and it's awesome! I want something similar for reCAPTCHA.

My problem is that I want to provision a web site that uses email + web server and will most likely be deployed by people with little technical knowledge so I want to automate as much as possible and use APIs for everything.

Can I do this with reCAPTCHA? Thank you!